# Webpack bundles PNG image but React won't display it

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, bundle

As the title says, webpack builds without complaint. And I can see the image file has been copied to the bundle output `dist` directory, so presumably the *test* part of the config is correct at least.

But the webpage can't locate it, it's just a broken image square. I must have read about 15 existing SO posts but here I am. I've tried both `import` version and `require` version:

`import red_light from './red_light.png';`

... or alternatively...

`const red_light = require('./red_light.png');`

with

`<img src={red_light} />`

Both fail to locate the image and load it onto the page.

Also tried directly requiring in the JSX:

`<img src={require('./red_light.png')} />`.

Fails too.

Webpack rules config:

```
...
rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {loader: "babel-loader"}
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: false
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        // options: {
        //   name: '[path][name].[ext]',
        // },
      },
    ]
...
```

I don't know what could be causing my setup not to work.

This seemed interesting to me: in browser when inspecting the emitted html, it just says `src=[Object module]` instead of any URL. Maybe this is normal.  When I hover my mouse it just says 'Could not load the image'.

Edit: I've discovered it works in *dev* mode but not *prod* mode, i.e. when everything's in RAM it all works out, but if I do an `npm run build` it emits the image(s) to (a sub-directory of) the configured webpack output directory, but the relative imports don't appear to be working inside the target `index.bundle.js`.  The prod html file can import the emitted js index file fine of course, since the page loads. I don't see why webpack doesn't have enough information to configure the correct relative import since i) it emitted the png file itself and ii) it can see the react source code and knows where every component is relative to the corresponding entry point.  Basically to make it work it looks like in prod I would have to import the png file into the react file but for the `src` attribute inside the `img` tag, manually write in an relative path as an external file.

`url-loader` is working fine, however, as there's no vector for confusion with relative imports in target versus src.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `use: [file-loader]` instead of `loader: "file-loader"`?

Comment: Tried a bunch of variations, with braces and square brackets. Webpack hasn't complained about any of them, results are the same. It appears webpack config will accept a few formats here (can someone confirm?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this

```
{
  test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
  loader: "file-loader"
},
```

You can view my full config [here](https://github.com/SaiGonSoftware/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/AwesomeCMSCore/webpack.config.js)

Update: Normally webpack try to search the file that live within the output dir in your config like this

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "wwwroot/dist"),
    filename: "[name].js",
    publicPath: "/dist/"
},
```

So it will look for the file inside the wwwroot folder

Comment: Just to check, does the image have to be anywhere in particular relative to entry points? In my case my image is in a subdirectory of the single entry point, imported into a js file inside './components'. I don't think there are any problems with my webpack config because the file is being located and emitted. It's just not displaying in the page.

Comment: Is there any error in your browser console when you run your code ?

Comment: No error. I can inspect the html in dev tools and the filename has been inserted into the emitted `img` tag's `src` attribute. I think it must be me not understanding how `npm run build` is supposed to work with bundled images. Or maybe a directory permission in the target. Moved away from blaming webpack anyway. Just got it working with `url-loader` and moved on. Learned a lesson in the simplicity of inlining the assets today. Cheers

Comment: @JSStuball I just updated my answer can you check it again ?